# Typography of unit symbols for Molar and Liter in siunitx

Tags: siunitx

The `siunitx` [manual](http://mirror.macomnet.net/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/siunitx/siunitx.pdf) suggests using `\DeclareSIUnit\Molar{\textsc{m}}` as the symbol for Molar but this creates a small cap M. This is (apparently) how Molar was defined in version 1 of `siunitx`. However, L for Liter is upper case, not small cap, which creates (at least to me) typographical conflict. Is there a typographical or other standard I am not aware of for these symbols, or should I simply use an upper case M for Molar?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\DeclareSIUnit\Molar{\textsc{m}} % pg. 39 siunitx manual (2013/03/11)

\begin{document}

\si{\Molar} \si{\liter}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I suppose the use of `\textsc{m}` for "Molar" is intended, in part, to avoid confusion with `M`, which is a common abbreviation for "Mega". Since (to the best of my knowledge) there's no similar use of `L`, there's no danger of confusion arising when one encounters an `L` in some expression, right?

Comment: @Mico - You may be right. We would not want to confuse Megameter with Megamolar! :) I just looked at the NIST Guide for the Use of the International System of Units and they use a small cap M for molar solutions (but only to say they are obsolete). They use an italic M for molar mass (kg/mol), which would also potentially cause confusion.

Comment: Small caps 'M' for molar is common in chemistry journals, hence the suggestion. On the other hand, small caps 'L' is only ever used for L/D stereochemistry, so for litres (if used), an upper case L is typical. (I'd always use cm3 for volume anyway, as historically there were some issues with litres.)